# Setting up Klov with Extent Reports, Builds are shown but no projects available

Tags: c#, mongodb, specflow, extentreports

I am trying to set up Klov for the first time with a new project. I have installed the correct version of mongodb and have the klov jar. I run both in the cmd prior to running my test. When I go to view my Klov report in the browser I see that the builds are occurring however there are no projects listed in the "select your project:" drop down. Does anybody know why I may be having this error?

I followed other suggestions but it seems like klov syntax has changed.

```
    private static ExtentKlovReporter klov;

        var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(@"C:file/path/.html");
        htmlReporter.Config.Theme = AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter.Configuration.Theme.Dark;

        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);

        klov = new ExtentKlovReporter();

        klov.InitMongoDbConnection("localhost", 27017);

        klov.ProjectName = "ExecuteAutomation Test";

        klov.InitKlovServerConnection("http://localhost:5689");

        klov.ReportName = "Time "+ DateTime.Now.ToString();


        extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);


    }
```

I see the builds but no projects.

Answer (score 0):

In extent.attach report you need to attach Klov report as well

Comment: Please provide more details in the explanation and if possible some reference to documentation.

Comment: In this line 
        extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
you are adding only htmlReporter you need to add kloc as well
like         extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter,klov);

Answer (score 0):

instead of  extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter); you need to call
extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter,klov);